# Points of intersection of summand of sums of squares of real polynomials

Tags: real-algebraic-geometry, sums-of-squares, real-algebra

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
\newcommand\Q{\mathbb Q}
$I am thinking of something related to Blekhermans 2012 paper *Nonnegative Polynomials and Sums of Squares* (Journal of the AMS, 25, 2012, 617-635).

Suppose $f,g\in \R[x,y]$ are cubics over real algebraic numbers such that $f^2+g^2 \in \Q[x,y]$ and such that the vanishing set of $f$ and $g$ consists of $9$ distinct real points. Is it true that in this case $f$ and $g$ will have all their coefficients in a real Galois field extension of $\Q$? Could we find (easy) examples such that the Galois closure of the smallest field containing their coefficients is not real?